# Lista de colores en DropdownList

Tags: asp.net

ya eh logrado que cuando selecciono un item en el dropdownlist este me pinte  una fila  completa pero cuando realiza el autopostback al seleccionar otro item este cambia el color y no se almacena en la fila siguiente. no se que tengo mal, estoy realizando la condicion en el evento RowDatabound de asp.net #

protected void GVProspecto_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < GVProspecto.Rows.Count; count++)
        {

```
            if (dpColor.SelectedValue == "1")
            {
                GVProspecto.Rows[count].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                return;
            }

           if (dpColor.SelectedValue == "2")
            {
                GVProspecto.Rows[count].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes agregar los estilos del lado de la pagina

```
 <style type="text/css">
        .formato1
        {
            color: red;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 14pt;
        }
          .formato2
        {
            color: blue;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 13pt;
        }
</style>
```

despues suponiendo que en el drop down no tiene los mismos nombres declarados en el estilo pero hacen refencia a digamos un color de fondo

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //suponiendo que quieres cambiar la columna inicial
           var    fila = GVProspecto.Columns[0];

        string css = DpColor.SelectedValue;
     switch (css)


                   {

      case "Rojo":



                        fila.ItemStyle.CssClass = "formato1";
                        break;
                    case "CSS Azul":

                        fila.ItemStyle.CssClass = "formato2";
                         break;

}
}
```

Basicamente esa es la idea